Remove repetition of code due to if condition
I have below code in my ts file.
    const modNames = ['CW652', 'MNOP200', '100ABCD', 'XYZ200'];
    if (model && modNames.includes(model) && !this.installed && !isActive) {
      this.route = true;
      this.stop = false;
    } else if (model && !modNames.includes(model) && this.installed && !isActive) {
      this.route = true;
      this.stop = false;
    } else {
      this.route = false;
      this.stop = true;
    }

My business logic inside first two if conditions is same. Is it possible to combine first two if in one?

Three things you can use to optimise:

You can assign the boolean expression directly to the boolean property, avoiding the if construct. As model is not yet a boolean, coerce it into one with !!.
Comparing the second condition with the first shows that you want the includes() result to have an opposite boolean value compared to this.installed, so just use the !== operator to cover for both cases in one expression.
this.stop is always the opposite of this.route, so use that fact.

Updated:
this.route = !!model && modNames.includes(model) !== this.installed && !isActive;
this.stop = !this.route;

